# How to make function that operates on lazy lists (aka "Streams")?

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I have to make function, that takes two lazy lists and operator (like +, -, *, /) and return one one lazy list after operation. For example, [1;2;3], [2;3;4;5] +, will return [3;5;7;5]. Lazy list introduced like regular because it more readable.

I have idea how it can be, but I have an error after the function() ->. It says This expression has type
         int lazyList * int lazyList * char -> int lazyList
       but an expression was expected of type int lazyList.

```
type 'a lazyList = LNil | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList);;

let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator = function
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '+' -> LCons(xA + xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '+')
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '-' -> LCons(xA - xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '-')
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '/' -> LCons(xA / xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '/')
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '*' -> LCons(xA * xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '*')
| LNil, LNil, _ -> LNil
| LNil, LCons(x, xf), _ -> LCons(x, function() -> xf())
| LCons(x, xf), LNil, _ -> LCons(x, function() -> xf())
| LCons(_), LCons(_), _ -> failwith "Not existible operator"
;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator = function
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '+' ->
```

says that evaluating `ldzialanie x y z` produces a *function* that takes a triple as argument.
That's not what you want - you want `ldzialanie x y z` to produce a `'a lazyList`.

You want to *match* on the arguments instead.
You also need to force the tails of your lazy lists when recursing - the recursion needs a `'a lazyList`, not a `unit -> 'a lazyList`.
As a third point, `function () -> xf()` is equivalent to `xf`.

```
let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator = match listA, listB, operator with
    LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '+' -> LCons(xA + xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '+')
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '-' -> LCons(xA - xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '-')
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '/' -> LCons(xA / xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '/')
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '*' -> LCons(xA * xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '*')
  | LNil, LNil, _ -> LNil
  | LNil, LCons(x, xf), _ -> LCons(x, xf)
  | LCons(x, xf), LNil, _ -> LCons(x, xf)
  | LCons(_), LCons(_), _ -> failwith "Not existible operator"
;;
```

Let's shorten this a bit.

If you look at the "nil cases", the result when one argument is `LNil` is the other argument.

```
let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator = match listA, listB, operator with
    LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '+' -> LCons(xA + xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '+')
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '-' -> LCons(xA - xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '-')
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '/' -> LCons(xA / xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '/')
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '*' -> LCons(xA * xB, function() -> ldzialanie (xfA()) (xfB()) '*')
  | LNil, r, _ -> r
  | l, LNil, _ -> l
  | LCons(_), LCons(_), _ -> failwith "Not existible operator"
;;
```

There's still a lot of duplication in the "non-nil" cases, and it's not completely obvious that the recursion is correct.
If you convert the operator character to a function first, you can condense those to just one case.

I would also let the operator argument go first so you can define for instance `let add_lists = ldzialanie (+)`.

Something like this:

```
let to_function x = match x with
    '+' -> ( + )
  | '*' -> ( * )
  | '/' -> ( / )
  | '-' -> ( - )
  | _ -> failwith "Non-existent operator";;

let rec ldzialanie_helper op listA listB = match listA, listB with
    LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB) -> LCons(op xA xB, function() -> ldzialanie_helper op (xfA()) (xfB()))
  | LNil, r  -> r
  | l, LNil  -> l;;

let ldzialanie op = ldzialanie_helper (to_function op);;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's a some confusion here

```
let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator = function
    | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB)
```

You're saying `ldzialanie` applied to the arguments `listA`, `listB` and `operator` returns a function. And that function you return takes triple, on which you pattern match.

Rather you should be using `match` to pattern match on the arguments of `ldzialanie`,

```
let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator = match listA, listB, operator with
    LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '+' ->
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '-' ->
```

Or if you prefer to define `ldzialanie` using `function` you have to keep in mind that the function is `ldzialanie` and not `ldzialanie listA listB operator`.

```
let rec ldzialanie2 = function 
     LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '+' ->
   | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '-' ->
```

Also note both versions have different types since the latter takes a triple as an argument.

```
ldzialanie  : int lazyList -> int lazyList -> char -> int lazyList 
ldzialanie2 : int lazyList * int lazyList * char -> int lazyList
```

You need to keep that in mind when making the recursive call.

Regarding how you calculate the result, you should be aware that given
`LCons(xA, xfA)` the type of `xfA` is not `'a lazyList` but `unit -> 'a lazyList`. So you can't pass `xfA` as an argument where you need a `'a lazyList`.